# Detect if textedit endswith domain extention

Tags: java, android

I am building an android application that utilizes web view and I am not sure how to check if the users input in a textedit named urlBar ends with one of the domain extentions in an array named extensions. Any guidance on why this doesn't work and how to fix it is highly appreciated. Thanks!

**Array:**

```
String[] extensions = {".com",".net",".org",".gov",".edu",".us",".darpa",".ru"};
```

**Button click code:**

```
public void buttonOnClick(View v) {
    if (urlBar.length() > 0 && urlBar.getText().toString().endsWith(extensions)) {
        webView1.loadUrl(urlBar.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: loop through your `extensions`, an check for `.endsWith` for each of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easy as **Vladyslav Matviienko** comment.

Just you have to wrap your code with loop:

```
public void buttonOnClick(View v) {
   for(String ext: extensions){ 
     if (urlBar.length() > 0 && urlBar.getText().toString().endsWith(ext)) {
         webView1.loadUrl(urlBar.getText().toString());
         break;
     }
   }
}
```